# Windows Phone 8 - Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

I have a WP8 Pivot application which contains a Model that is meant to automatically bind against the View/Page.xaml. This is done by the auto-generated `NotfifyPropertyChanged` code which I have assigned to all of the properties that are spat out on to the page.

The problem as I see it is when the application is installed for the first time, the Model is obviously empty as the application is completely fresh. At this point, I call a web service which successfully retrieves data. Once retrieved, I save the data and assign the data to the Model.

Although I assign the data to the model, the View doesn't update itself. I also noticed that the `NotifyPropertyChanged` code doesn't fire when doing:

```
App.ViewModel.Signs = results.Signs
```

The code for the Model looks like this:

```
public int ID
{
    get { return _id; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _id)
        {
            _id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the properties have the same notion, i.e. `NotifyPropertyChanged("objectName");`.

When I relaunch the application, the information on the screen successfully appears. It is only when the application fires from beginning or when the user manually asks for the latest data that it fails to update the View/Page.xaml.

Any ideas what I could do to fix this?

Comment: does the Signs property also call NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Is value == _id and not hitting the notify in your property setter?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `NotifyPropertyChanged` method is broken, or the `Signs` property does not call the method correctly.